# Unknown provider error when configuring ng-token-auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am trying to configure [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#configuration), for `angularjs` app I am creating, But I am getting followoing error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module RDash due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: o
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=o
r/<@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:381
Xe/x.$injector<@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:19793
r@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:18963
i@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:19300
r@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:18343
p/<@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:18475
o@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:786
p@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:18252
Xe@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:19942
ae/s@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:7465
ae@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:7775
oe@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:7023
@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:5:27591
r@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:3:30513
We/n@http://localhost:8888/lib/js/main.min.js:1:16341
```

Here is my `module.js`:

```
angular.module('RDash', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ng-token-auth'])

.config(
    function($authProvider) {
        $authProvider.configure({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
        });
    });
```

Here are dependencies in bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "rdash-ui": "1.0.*",
    "angular": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.10",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
    "ng-token-auth": "~0.0.28",
    "ng-resource": "~0.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: Seems you have a component that is not *minification-safe*. Open `main.min.js` line 1 column 381 and guess which one.

Comment: At least it should be `.config(['$authProvider', function($authProvider) {...}])`.

Comment: Agreed, you are not set up for minification. All of your dependencies need to be defined as string literals or manually injected so the compiler can correctly map them.

Comment: @buzzsaw: What do you mean by `set up for minification`, How do I setup for it and how do I know these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not set up for minification. Anything that has utilizes injection should be properly set up to allow for this. You are getting an unknown provider "o" which is caused by not following one of the two below methods.

Method 1:

```
var controller = function($scope, $http) {
  ...
}

controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']
```

Method 2:

```
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
}])
```

Assuming this started happening when you added in the $authProvider, I would start looking there. Any associated code in the provider itself should also be checked.

```
.config(["$authProvider", function($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.configure({
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried Method-2, which worked. How to do I understand what is going on here, any good resources to learn these?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the angular docs have a good reference on array notation for injection. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Or, you can google something like "Prepare angularjs for minification" to get more examples of this.